# How to fix a strange behavior of an Icon wrapped into TouchableOpacity?

Tags: react-native

I have a MapView inside which I have a fixed market for the user to drag the map and set the current location, a button to save the changes and an icon wrapped into the touchable opacity to set the current location. 
My problem is that sometimes the Icon inside wrapping TouchableOpacity appears at the top right corner.

[image: gif]

code for the MapView

```
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => { }}
        >
          <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
            initialRegion={region || initialCoordinates}
            ref={(el) => { this.mapViewModal = el }}
          >
            <View pointerEvents="none" style={[styles.markerFixed, { marginBottom: 52 }]}>
              <Ionicons style={styles.marker} pointerEvents="none" name="ios-pin" size={72} />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setMapCurrentLocation} style={styles.arrowWrapper}>
              <FontAwesome name="location-arrow" style={styles.locationArrow} size={42} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </MapView>
          <View style={styles.mapButtonWrapper}>
            <RkButton
              style={styles.mapButton}
              onPress={this.handleAdjustClick}
            >
              {i18n.t('Adjust')}
            </RkButton>
          </View>
        </Modal>
```

styles:

```
 arrowWrapper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 100,
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    padding: 5,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 75,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  },
  locationArrow: {
    color: primaryColor,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by moving out the TouchableOpacity out of the MapView and wrapping into View:

```
  <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      visible={modalVisible}
      onRequestClose={() => { }}
    >
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
        initialRegion={region || initialCoordinates}
        ref={(el) => { this.mapViewModal = el }}
      >
        <View pointerEvents="none" style={[styles.markerFixed, { marginBottom: 52 }]}>
          <Ionicons style={styles.marker} pointerEvents="none" name="ios-pin" size={72} />
        </View>
      </MapView>
      <View style={styles.arrowWrapper}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setMapCurrentLocation}>
          <FontAwesome name="location-arrow" style={styles.locationArrow} size={42} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.mapButtonWrapper}>
        <RkButton
          style={styles.mapButton}
          onPress={this.handleAdjustClick}
        >
          {i18n.t('Adjust')}
        </RkButton>
      </View>
    </Modal>
```